# Keras tensorflow modify model NN to CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to rewrite a Neural Network model which used to classify satellite images,
I want to use some conv layers in that model,like
   `#keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same',input_shape=(1,nBands)),`
but I can't get the  `input_shape` parameter right, can anyone help me?

the previous NN model is this:

```py
# Print the shape of reshaped data
print(xTrain.shape, xTest.shape, featuresHyderabad.shape)
#(2519025, 1, 6) (1679351, 1, 6) (1391808, 1, 6)
# Define the parameters of the model
model = keras.Sequential([

    #keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same',input_shape=(1,nBands)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, nBands)), 
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')])

# Define the accuracy metrics and parameters
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

# Run the model
model.fit(xTrain, yTrain, epochs=2,batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape must be the shape of the images. for exemple if you train your model with 48x48 black and white images the input shape will be (48,48, 1) or (1, 48, 48) if the chanel value is placed before the height and width.

Comment: Thank you!!but the image has been reshaped , the original article is [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-for-satellite-data-classification-using-tensorflow-in-python-a13bcf38f3e1)

Comment: ok, so the image are flattened in 1D, so you have to use conv1D (instead of conv2D) with the same input shape that you already have, or you will have to remove the reshape step so the image is still in 2D

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use the Conv1D layer like this: `keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3), activation='relu', padding = 'same',input_shape=(2519025,  6)),
`, but I got this waring:`WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 2519025, 6) for input Tensor("conv1d_input:0", shape=(None, 2519025, 6), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 6).`,  how can I solve this?

Comment: what is the number 2519025?

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and I think you'll find CNNs perform much better than training NNs on flattened images.  For the input shape in `Conv2D` layers, the shape can be given in one of two forms:

1. "Channels last" (Keras uses this by default): `(image height, image width, 6)`, where `6` refers to the number of channels (`3` for RGB, `1` for grayscale).
2. "Channels first" (you can select this option by setting `data_option="channels_first"` when you define the `Conv2D` layer):  `(6, image height, image width)`.

On a more intuitive note, you can think of the input size as being the size of the image you are giving to the network, which is `(image height, image width, number of bands)`.  I found this documentation from Keras helpful as well: https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/.

Comment: Thank you!! the original satellite image size is  2054 *2044, and i believe it has 6 channels, but it has been reshaped to a two-dimensional array then reshaped to three-dimensions, such that each row represents an individual pixel. I tried all possible figures like  (2054, 2044,6),(2519025, 1, 6) still got the same error result, the original article is here: https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-for-satellite-data-classification-using-tensorflow-in-python-a13bcf38f3e1